# Specify return type based on other template argument

Tags: c++, templates, return-type, function-templates

I'd like to specify my templated function's return type, by an other template argument. All of this inside a class.

In the header file:

```
class MyClass {
    template<int type, typename RT>
    RT myfunc();
};
```

In the .cpp something like this:

```
template<>
int MyClass::myfunc<1, int>() { return 2; }

template<>
double MyClass::myfunc<2, double>() { return 3.14; }

template<>
const char* MyClass::myfunc<3, const char*>() { return "some string"; }
```

And I would like to be able to use my function like this:

```
MyClass m;
int i = m.myfunc<1>(); // i will be 2
double pi = m.myfunc<2>(); // pi will be 3.14
const char* str = m.myfunc<3>(); // str == "some string"
```

So I would like my function to be able to parameterized by one template integer (or enumeration whatsoever), and the return type will be different, based on this integer. 
I don't want the function to work with any other integer arguments than the specified ones, for example here `m.myfunc<4>()` would give compile error.

I want to parameterize my function by one template argument only, because `m.myfunc<1, int>()` would be working, but I don't want to write the typename all the time.

I tried with auto return types, or templating other way around, but always got some compile errors. (Function not found, unresolved externals...)

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Specializations like `template<>
int myfunc<1, int>(){ return 2; }` should be defined in header file if you want them to be used outside that `.cpp` file.

Comment: Still gives compile error with `could not deduce template argument for 'RT' ` when used as `m.myfunc<1>();`

Comment: @c-smile They should be *declared* in a header file (not sure if this is necessary, though). The definition must not be included in multiple translation units, otherwise you violate the ODR (since those functions are not templates any more, not inline and don't seem to have internal linkage).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you seek?

```
template<int n>
struct Typer
{
};

template<>
struct Typer<1>
{
    typedef int Type;
};
template<>
struct Typer<2>
{
    typedef double Type;
};
template<>
struct Typer<3>
{
    typedef const char* Type;
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    template<int typeCode>
    typename Typer<typeCode>::Type myfunc();
};

template<> Typer<1>::Type MyClass::myfunc<1>(){ return 2; } 

template<> Typer<2>::Type MyClass::myfunc<2>() { return 3.14; }

template<> Typer<3>::Type MyClass::myfunc<3>() { return "some string"; }
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! Works fine. I had to define the Typer structs inside the header, but I didn't had to declare the template specializations in the header, only in the .cpp file.